# How to overwrite local tags with git fetch?

Tags: git

How to overwrite local tags with git fetch?
I want to replace local tags with remote tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git fetch --tags` will do it.

From the [docs](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-fetch.html) (description of the `--tags` parameter):

> Most of the tags are fetched automatically as branch heads are downloaded, but tags that do not point at objects reachable from the branch heads that are being tracked will not be fetched by this mechanism. This flag lets all tags and their associated objects be downloaded. The default behavior for a remote may be specified with the remote.<name>.tagopt setting.

As per gerrard00's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55268620/292067), the `--force` parameter is necessary to overwrite local tags in git Ver2.20 or newer. (The full command being `git fetch --tags --force`)

Comment: But I am asking how to overwrite existing local tags, because they were wrongly created

Comment: `git fetch --tags` will in fact update existing local tags, e.g., if remote tag FOO maps to 1234567 and local tag FOO maps to fedcba9, `git fetch --tags` will replace FOO with 1234567.

Comment: Update: in newer versions of git, this will no longer update local tags.  You can force-update them instead, with `git fetch <remote> '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'` (`--force` might also work, but I have not tested this).

Comment: `git fetch --tags --force` does indeed overwrite local tags with remote ones.

Answer (score 80):

As of Git 2.20 you need to explicitly specify the force flag:

`git fetch origin --tags --force`

> Until Git version 2.20, and unlike when pushing with git-push[1], any updates to refs/tags/* would be accepted without + in the refspec (or --force). When fetching, we promiscuously considered all tag updates from a remote to be forced fetches. Since Git version 2.20, fetching to update refs/tags/* works the same way as when pushing. I.e. any updates will be rejected without + in the refspec (or --force).
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: Is there a way to get git to always do this when fetching?

Comment: A git pull is a fetch followed by a merge. So the fetch is still the solution.

Comment: Or just `git fetch --tags --force` for current remote.

Answer (score 12):

`git fetch --tags --all --prune`

This will explicitly tell git to fetch, and at the same time, remove tags which no longer exist on the remote.

Comment: This does not appear to remove tags that were only ever present locally.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels, git can not distinguish between a tag that was never pushed and a tag that was removed from the remote.

Comment: Perhaps @lightonphiri meant to use `--prune-tags` instead of just `--prune` ?

Answer (score 1):

Tags won't be overwritten, because they are meant to be sort-of immutable. If you want to have an object that is (realistically) changable, use a branch pointer or a ref instead.
That leaves you with: git tag -d *tagname*..., and then fetching it again.

Comment: I don't agree with your first statement--This would distort the whole point of using a VCS don't you think?

Comment: Git does not encourage re-writing (already shared, remote) history. That doesn't defeat the point of a VCS – which is to keep history! In most cases it's possible to force such things to happen but it can cause quite a few problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, unlike for branches, git does not track remote tags different from local tags. Once finished fetching, they are indistinguishable.

- does update the local tag (even though the manual doesn’t tell)

  - `git fetch --tags`
- does not update the local tag

  - `git fetch`
  - `git fetch --prune`
  - `git fetch --prune --force`

A tag update/overwrite looks like this:

```
From git:path/name
 - [tag update]      my_tag -> my_tag
```

This works for lightweight and annotated tags, even mixed. That is: an annotated tag might be overwritten with a lightweight one and vice versa.

<sub>I used git version 2.7.4</sub>

Comment: note: this does not delete tags that were deleted on the remote

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Your comment suggests that you believe there is a way to do that, but there isn’t. You can indeed delete all local tags not existing on the remote, but that also deletes _local tags which were never on the remote at all_ (e.g. not yet pushed, or tags for local-only purposes). There is no way to delete only tags which were _deleted on the remote_.

Comment: Not sure why you think that my comment is suggesting that - I never wrote there is a way to do it!?!. I just tried to complement your answer because nowhere it states that local tags are not deleted and "does update the local tag" could be understood as also removing a tag that was removed on the remote. I think it was a clear statement (without any hidden suggestions)... but my English is probably worse than I think.