# How to overwrite tags in local git repository?

Tags: git

I have local clone of git repository where I created new tag. I didn't push that tag to remote repository. I would like to revert local list of tags to match remote. How can I achieve that?

I have check solution from [How to overwrite local tags with git fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662249/how-to-overwrite-local-tags-with-git-fetch) but without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just delete the local tag(s):

```
git tag -d <tag>
```

And then re-fetch tags from the remote:

```
git fetch --tags
```

If you want to delete all your local tags:

```
git tag | xargs -n1 git tag -d
```

Comment: Method with removing all tags works. Tags in my local repository are created automatically by failing maven release. So now I can remove them automatically with a script. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I read in `git help tag` that `git tag -d` does what you want.